# Duration of FLV files

Tags: windows-8, video, flv, media-info

On windows, I can usually see the total duration of multiple video files of formats like (.avi, .wmv) under properties dialogue.

[image]

But I cannot see the duration of all the FLV files this way. I have tried WMV and MPC player and they won't show it either.

What can I do to view the duration of multiple flv files?

Comment: Windows doesn't natively support FLV containers. Maybe try installing a codec pack and see if that helps.

Comment: @slhck: I have a Mega codec pack installed with Media Player Classic and WMC as a part of Windows 8 Pro but still it doesn't seem to support.

Answer (score 1):

The windows base OS does not interact with the metadata file in a .flv file even with codecs as most codecs are built to play a file not analyse it for you OS.

The metadata stored in a .flv file is as follows:

- "duration" - 64-bit IEEE floating point value in seconds
- "width" and "height" – 64-bit IEEE floating point value in pixels
- "framerate" – 64-bit IEEE floating point value in frames per second
- "keyframes" – an array with the positions of p-frames, needed when random access is sought.
- "|AdditionalHeader" - an array of required stream decoding informational pairs

  - "Encryption" - an array of required encryption informational pairs
  - "Metadata" - Base64 encoded string of Adobe Access DRM scheme data containing the decryption key required

In the end flv, f4v, ect... are designed for use as embedded video. Windows has probably not built in this functionality due to this but you can always write your own dll files to handle this or find 3rd party software such as [flvmdv](http://www.buraks.com/flvmdv/) to view this meta data

Comment: Thanks for the answer it was informative. Apparently FLVMDV supports Windows XP only as mentioned on their link.

Comment: I'm not surprised the last update was 2006... you can test it with win 8 but like I said there isn't a need for it as FLV isn't really a good solution outside of embedded web videos. Even these days the avg internet speeds mean that FLV isn't your best option for that due to quality issues with the standard